# MYSQL 5.7 UPDATE value with ternary (perform a true/false toggle)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to toggle a table column between true and false. My most recent attempt--

`UPDATE favorites SET favorited = (IF(favorited=true, 'false', 'true')) WHERE title="${recipe}"`

--is giving me the following error:

`ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'true'`

Can any MYSQL geniuses guide me towards the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning strings from the IF i.e. `'false', 'true'` return booleans instead

```
UPDATE favorites 
    SET favorited = (IF(favorited=true, false, true)) .....
```

> *Small Note* Genius not required in this case :)

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response! I tried your solution, got the same error, then realized that I had set the datatype of that column to VARCHAR, so I put quotes around all the values and that solved my issue, like so:
`UPDATE favorites SET favorited = (IF(favorited='true', 'false', 'true')) WHERE title="${recipe}"`

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of the column `favorited` is `BOOLEAN` then what you are doing is the negation of the current value so all you need is the operator `NOT`:

```
UPDATE favorites 
SET favorited = not favorited
WHERE title="${recipe}"
```